# How to prevent the loss of excellent answers to poor questions.

Tags: discussion

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/539174/28900) has rightly been closed for lack of context, which the OP has proved unwilling or unable to attempt to provide. At present, it has two votes for deletion, and I fear it isn't long for the world.

This seems a tragedy to me, not for the loss of the question, but for the loss of rschwieb's answer, which is one of the best I've seen on the site to date.

---

This sort of thing is certain to crop up again, as it has happened in the past. So, I wonder, what (if anything) can be done to preserve answers despite the questions?

Comment: Edit the question to improve it?

Comment: The delete votes may, at least partly, be a reaction to the OP's misguided *zero is neither even nor odd* campaign (and related yelling into wind). Ok, the question is also just bad. I don't know what is the best course of action here. Locking the question as a historical relic is a possibility. That will also disable all voting. How do users feel about the possibility? Letting nature take its course is also an alternative, but many may feel that the thread (in its entirey) is worth preserving.

Comment: @Jyrki: I would certainly support locking it. The thread is certainly informative, even the misguided parts.

Comment: +1 for bringing this up. Better to have the discussion now as opposed to after couple rounds of a delete/undelete bout have allowed users to dig themselves into a deep trench.

Comment: @mrf: I considered that, but the OP has shown a penchant for vandalizing his own posts when he doesn't like them anymore, and I fear any such edit would only begin a war of the rollbacks.

Comment: @CameronBuie The OP [seems to want to leave](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/21797/how-to-delete-account-on-stacknetwork), so after they left, the danger of vandalising an edited post is small. Since three more delete votes are needed, it's probably not going to be deleted _soon_, and if it is edited, it could be kept unlocked. (If somebody makes a really good edit, it could even be reopened, yay.)

Comment: A thing to consider: I have not discussed this with other moderators, but "locking for historical reasons" should, IMO, not become a standard solution to all contested threads. It would be counterproductive to litter the site with such relics (may be even abuse of that feature). There should be something exceptional about the questions given such a treatment.

Comment: The situation is very particular here: OP vandalizes their own questions, preventing improvements; but OP is about to leave the site; there are three largely unrelated questions in one (and the third one barely makes sense), which is completely unacceptable; but the interesting part of rschwieb's answer is only about one of the three. Is your question a general one (as the title suggests) or about this particular case? In any case you could probably edit your question (either the title or the body, and the tags in both cases, it's not a feature request by any stretch of imagination...).

Comment: Then I'm pretty sure mrf's comment is the answer (and the counterargument you've offered doesn't apply in general, most users aren't as stubborn as OP here): if you don't want a question to be deleted for whatever reason (including "it has great answers", "I like it", "I answered it and want to keep the rep"), but the question is about to be deleted because it's not good enough, then edit it to improve it. Or even ask someone else how to improve it if you don't know how (I've seen that happen a few times in the RUCD chat room).

Comment: Here I think simply keeping the question "Is zero prime?" and adding a few lines like "A prime number is a number that cannot be divided, and you cannot divide zero items into more parts, but I've read that 2 is the smallest prime, what's happening here?", or "Zero is a very special number, I know the definition of prime but does it also apply in this special case?" or something to that effect would be enough to get the question reopened. Maybe also links to other questions were zero behaves bizarrely in arithmetic.

Comment: @Najib Idrissi: I don't support other people writing "I" in the question, because that gives to the wrong impression that the sentence was written by the OP, who is the "I" in that context.

Comment: @Carl  first-person narrative is a well-established style.

Comment: @quid: I am not sure what you are saying. Sure, the first person is part of English and other languages. But on Stackexchange the "I" in the question refers to the person asking the quesion, not to some hypothetical person who might ask a related question. We don't want to put words in the mouth of the OP, or tell them what they do and don't understand.

Comment: @Carl my point is that there are plenty of novels, short stories etc where the "I" does not refer to the author. You say 'But on Stackexchange [sic] the "I" in the question refers to the person asking the question' no it does not (necessarily).' This is just false in this generality. See  [one of many examples](http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/833/who-are-the-mathoverflow-moderators) where the author of the post writes "I" yet certainly does not intend to refer to themselves.

Comment: @Carl If need be the whole thing can be rewritten from an impersonal point of view: "Zero is a very special number. The definition of a prime number is [...]. However zero sometimes behaves differently from other numbers, does the definition still apply? Why?" To be honest it doesn't matter much to me, but I understand if some people prefer that way.

Comment: @Najib Idrissi: I think that is preferable to writing a question that (perhaps misleadingly) suggests the OP wrote something about themselves that they did not write.

Comment: Your last sentence, which was not present originally I think,  can be a valid concern. However, OP can always correct and it is in principle transparent from the revision history. But granted, in potentially problematic cases one might just avoid the "I" (or even make the revision transparent in some way). Anyway, this seems like a detail. If it is *really* just about the "I." (@Carl  )

Comment: @Daniel: Is it possible to undelete a question that was originally posted by a user whose account has since been removed? If so, I will simply bide my time, and try to come up with an edit that makes it worth salvaging.

Comment: @CameronBuie Yes, whether the account of the OP has been deleted or not is completely irrelevant for that. Considering that the question has a couple of good answers, you wouldn't even need to make a brilliant edit to collect the necessary undeletion votes. Making it a sensible question would suffice. (I would recommend to remove the "odd or even" and "number" parts, the single "is $0$ prime" stands better alone.)

Comment: And when the question is edited (whether it has been deleted or not), please ping so we can clean up the comment thread(s).

Comment: @NajibIdrissi *the interesting part of rschwieb's answer is only about one of the three.* This is entirely counterfactual, and it leads to an interesting discussion about downplaying trivial parts of posts in favor of the interesting parts, but since this is neither here nor there in the current situation, I'll leave it at that. Veering back on topic (and addressing everyone now again) I bet there are quite a few cases of excellent answers on terrible questions, so this question seems pretty useful.

Comment: It would be nice if the question were rewritten. However, it's both difficult to change the content of the questions, and hard to change the quality since motivation for the question would have to be astroturfed. It's also problematic to alter the content of what is asked. I spent some time searching when this question was closed to see if "is zero prime?" appeared elsewhere on the site for inspiration, but I didn't have any luck. It seems like a question that would be on the site sooner or later,  regardless of the survival of this particular post.

Comment: @rschwieb Less than two lines and a half of your answer are about "Is 0 a number" and "Is zero even". Then you say yourself that the question "Is zero prime" is more interesting... What's the problem with adding context for the question later? Adding the context makes the question better: do you disagree with that? If not, what's the problem, exactly?

Comment: @NajibIdrissi *Less than two lines and a half of your answer are about "Is 0 a number" and "Is zero even".* Correct, and my claim is that suffices in a case like this. The challenge posed to you still stands: "what else do you expect?" Personally I don't see what else is worth saying that isn't a detriment to the discussion, but of course, someone else may be more resourceful. I did just get one idea for improvement, and thanks for that. Now to see if the materials exist...

Comment: @NajibIdrissi I guess I will backpedal and concede that evenness of $0$ doesn't suffer the problem I was thinking of (which "is zero a number?" still suffers), the real issue is that it's already well talked about and it would be suboptimal to duplicate such discussion. We wouldn't answer a new post of "is zero even" and so I shouldn't spend space answering it if it is embedded in another problem. Thanks for inspiring the edit I made to the post: it did incrementally improve it.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi *What's the problem with adding context for the question later?* I didn't say there was a problem with it, I just meant it was problematic in this case, meaning "hard to do right." *Adding the context makes the question better: do you disagree with that?* No, of course I agree with it: apparently we're speaking at cross purposes if you thought this question was necessary. *If not, what's the problem, exactly?* I guess "If so, what's the problem" was intended, and I guess I can skip this piece

Comment: @CameronBuie If you have an idea to improve the question, go ahead.

Comment: @mrf: I finally made an edit to the original post that (probably) addresses the poster's misunderstandings, and thereby provides sufficient context to improve the post. Please let me know whether you feel I've met that standard, or if you have further improvements to suggest.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: I finally made an edit to the original post that (probably) addresses the poster's misunderstandings, and thereby provides sufficient context to improve the post. Please let me know whether you feel I've met that standard, or if you have further improvements to suggest.

Comment: @DanielFischer: I finally made an edit to the original post that (probably) addresses the poster's misunderstandings, and thereby provides sufficient context to improve the post. Please let me know whether you feel I've met that standard, or if you have further improvements to suggest.

Comment: @CarlMummert: I finally made an edit to the original post that (probably) addresses the poster's misunderstandings, and thereby provides sufficient context to improve the post. Please let me know whether you feel I've met that standard, or if you have further improvements to suggest.

Comment: @quid: I finally made an edit to the original post that (probably) addresses the poster's misunderstandings, and thereby provides sufficient context to improve the post. Please let me know whether you feel I've met that standard, or if you have further improvements to suggest.

Comment: @CameronBuie I'd say improvement all around! Good work

Comment: @CameronBuie Definitely an improvement. I'm sitting on a fence. It still might be better to follow Najib Idrissi's solution and focus only on the question of primeness. That's the part rschwieb largely addressing also (unless I missed something).

Answer (score 10):

The general consensus in the comments above seems to be that the best approach, in general, is to edit the original post to improve the question, if at all possible. This approach is available to any user with $2000$ reputation or more (which I see no particular reason to adjust).

Perhaps worth further discussion is this: How important is it that such an edit be put in "impersonal language," so as to avoid misrepresenting the OP's original intentions and understanding? ([This](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/21800/how-to-prevent-the-loss-of-excellent-answers-to-poor-questions?noredirect=1#comment84928_21800) [is](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/21800/how-to-prevent-the-loss-of-excellent-answers-to-poor-questions?noredirect=1#comment84929_21800) [discussed](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/users/85306/quid) [in](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/21800/how-to-prevent-the-loss-of-excellent-answers-to-poor-questions?noredirect=1#comment84931_21800) [the](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/21800/how-to-prevent-the-loss-of-excellent-answers-to-poor-questions?noredirect=1#comment84932_21800) [comment](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/21800/how-to-prevent-the-loss-of-excellent-answers-to-poor-questions?noredirect=1#comment84933_21800) [thread](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/21800/how-to-prevent-the-loss-of-excellent-answers-to-poor-questions?noredirect=1#comment84934_21800) [above](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/21800/how-to-prevent-the-loss-of-excellent-answers-to-poor-questions?noredirect=1#comment84935_21800).)

Comment: I think it depends. Sometimes an edit  is just about moving up some information OP gave in the comments; in that case I think there is no harm in staying with the "I", but in fact try to mark it up sometimes as: info moved up form the comments. If OP is a deleted account or an anonymous inactive account, I also see no harm. If it is an established  active account it usually seems good to get OP involved. If somebody has qualms about writing "I"  they can avoid it. Everybody is responsible for their edits.

Comment: It also depends on the original style of the post and how harmonious it would be to add something neutral. In brief, I think it is a judgment call. In any case it is common on SE sites that "I" is used as a purely stylistic device as is quite common in all kinds of other places too, like FAQs all over the world.  Personally, I try to be careful not misrepresent somebodies intentions, but I also have no intention to go out of my way to avoid writing an "I" always except when it is not about me specifically just because of some idiosyncrasies.

Answer (score 4):

Another possibility [mentioned in the comments above](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21800/how-to-prevent-the-loss-of-excellent-answers-to-poor-questions/21805#comment84919_21800) is locking the post as a historical relic, which would preserve the post, but at the expense of disabling all voting on the question and its answers for the duration of its locking. Again, [as mentioned in the comments](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21800/how-to-prevent-the-loss-of-excellent-answers-to-poor-questions/21805#comment84924_21800), this is probably better as an exception to the general rule, as it could easily become counterproductive.

So, again in the name of furthering discussion, what sort(s) of things "should" the moderators look for in a post, to help them decide whether it ought to be classified as such a relic? Obviously, regardless of any commentary on this option, it will fall to the mods to make such determinations for themselves. Still, this gives the community a chance to weigh in on the question.